How to type a function that unwraps each value of a tuple, to then return a tuple of the unwrapped values
Given I have a type Validated with the following form:
type Valid<T> = { isValid: true, value: T };
type Invalid = { isValid: false };
type Validated<T> = Valid<T> | Invalid;

const valid = <T>(value: T): Valid => ({ isValid: true, value });
const Invalid : Invalid = { isValid: false };

How would I go about typing the following function so that the output represents a tuple in the same form as the arguments list?
const zip = (...items) => 
  items.every(item => item.isValid) 
    ? { isValid: true, value: items.map(item => item.value) }
    : { isValid: false };

Examples of what I want the type system to produce:
const result = zip(valid(1), valid("a"), valid("b"), valid(true));
// result is marked as Valid<[number, string, string, boolean]> | Invalid;

If the form of the function I described does not allow for this, then is there a form that does?
I tried the following form:
const isValid = <T>(item: Validated<T>): item is Valid<T> => item.isValid;

const allValid = <T>(items: Validated<T>[]): items is Valid<T>[] =>
  items.every((item) => item.isValid);

const zip = <T>(...items: Validated<T>[]) : Validated<T[]> =>
  items.every((item) => item.isValid)
    ? { isValid: true, value: items.map((item) => item.value) }
    : { isValid: false };

However this erases the positional-preserving type of the tuple and outputs something more akin to
Valid<[number | string | boolean]> | Invalid for the example from above.

Please [edit] to make sure your code is a [mre]. There's at least one place where you refer to the type Valid without its type argument, and all is not a method of arrays.

You want zip's rest parameter items to be a tuple type so that TypeScript can keep track of the type of each passed-in argument.  The approach you should take here is to make the function generic in the tuple type T of the output type argument. That is, you want zip(...items) to produce a result of type Validated<T>.  And then you can make items a mapped tuple type that wraps each element of T with Validated, like this:
const zip = <T extends any[]>(
    ...items: { [I in keyof T]: Validated<T[I]> }
): Validated<T> =>
    items.every(v => v.isValid) ?
        valid(items.map((item: Valid<any>) => item.value)) as Valid<T> :
        Invalid;

So when you call zip() with an argument list of type, say, [Validated<X>, Validated<Y>, Validated<Z>], TypeScript can match it to { [I in keyof T]: Validated<T[I]> } and infer that T is [X, Y, Z]. And the return type of that call is Validated<T>.
Note that inside the implementation, TypeScript isn't smart enough to understand that items.map(item => item.value) will be of type Valid<T> (at best it could verify Valid<T[keyof T]>[] or Valid<any>[]).  The language isn't expressive enough to model how map() acts on tuples; see Mapping tuple-typed value to different tuple-typed value without casts. So I needed to use the type assertion as Valid<T>.
Okay, let's test it out:
const result = zip(valid(1), valid("a"), valid("b"), valid(true));
//    ^? const result: Validated<[number, string, string, boolean]>

const hmm = zip(valid(1), Math.random() < 0.5 ? valid("a") : Invalid, valid(false));
//    ^? const hmm: Validated<[number, string, boolean]>

const also = zip(Invalid);
//    ^? const also: Validated<[unknown]>

Looks good!

Note that you haven't tried to ask TypeScript to detect whether the output will actually be Invalid or not.  This is possible but it's a lot more complicated and possibly fragile. One approach would be
declare const zip: <T extends Validated<any>[]>(...items: T) =>
    (Invalid extends T[number] ? Invalid : never) | (
        { [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends Invalid ? unknown : never }[number] extends never ?
        Valid<{ [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends Validated<infer U> ? U : never }> : never
    );

which tries to tease apart whether any argument can be Invalid (in which case Invalid is part of the result) or whether any argument is definitely Invalid (in which case Valid<⋯> is not part of the result).  I won't go into exactly how it works here because it's outside the scope of the question. But it produces these results:
const result = zip(valid(1), valid("a"), valid("b"), valid(true));
//    ^? const result: Valid<[number, string, string, boolean]>

const hmm = zip(valid(1), Math.random() < 0.5 ? valid("a") : Invalid, valid(false));
//    ^? const hmm: Invalid | Valid<[number, string, boolean]>

const also = zip(Invalid);
//    ^? const also: Invalid

Playground link to code

After playing around for a while I found a solution that worked.
export type Valid<T> = { isValid: true; value: T };
export type Invalid = { isValid: false };
export type Validated<T> = { isValid: true; value: T } | { isValid: false };

/** Converts a tuple type to a tuple of validated objects, presering the order */
type ValidatedObjs<Values extends {}[]> = {
  [Key in keyof Values]: Validated<Values[Key]>;
};

/**
 * Combines multiple `Validated<>` objects together.
 * The result is `Valid<>` iff all items in the array are `Valid<>`
 */
export const zip = <Values extends {}[]>(
  items: ValidatedObjs<Values>
): Validated<Values> => {
  const allValid = items.every((item) => item.isValid);

  if (!allValid) return { isValid: false };

  const values = items.map((item: any) => item.value) as Values;
  return { isValid: true, value: values };
};

It turned out the solution was to use the tuple type as the generic argument to zip and then translate that type to a list of Validated<> objects in the argument type for items. That way I could access the original tuple type, and the have the typing for the list of Validated<> objects.

This approach is how I'd do it. Is there a reason your zip accepts a single array instead a rest parameter? I thought you wanted it to be variadic.

@jcalz I like the approach you linked better. That is what I will be using going on. Also I did initially want the solution to be variadic, but the one I posted solved my issue in enough of a usable way to proceed with what I was working on, so I cared less if the solution was variadic. However, it's nice to see that your solution does work on variadic arguments, which is a big bonus. Thank you .

@jcalz Could you post an answer with your TS Playground code so that I can mark that as the answer. I think your solution is the best I have come across so far and solves all of my issues.
